# Angular Virtual Scroll display issues

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have been trying to find a solution for a couple of days for this, but can't seem to find one.

We have a lot of mat-cards loading and thought it best to add virtual-scrolling, however it immediately changed the display to rows (showing all the mat-cards stacked below one another). I have rewritten the section a couple of times to no avail.

```
<div fxLayout style="margin-top: 40px" class="row">
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport [itemSize]="20" class="example-viewport">
      <div fxFlex.gt-md="265px" fxFlex.lg="265px" *cdkVirtualFor="let course of courses | courseDrop : typeView | courseTemp: courseSearch">
        <mat-card class="course-card" >
         ...content
        </mat-card>
      </div>
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is the limitation for virtual scroll - it works with rows.

If you need to have items displayed next to each other, you need to split those in the component into groups and have the virtual scroll work on groups.

Since you're using breakpoints, you'd need to do some work on listening to breakpoint changes. You can do that by using the [MediaObserver](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/MediaObserver).

You would need to adjust the filtering or do it in the component. I'm leaving that out.

```
function split<T>(input: T[], groupSize: number): T[][]  {
  const out: T[][] = [];
  for(let i=0; i < input.length; i += groupSize) {
    out.push(input.slice(i, i + groupSize));
  }
  return out;
}


mediaObserver.media$.subscribe((change: MediaChange) => {
      
      if ( change.mqAlias == 'xs') {
         this.viewCourses = split(this.courses,1);
      }
      if ( change.mqAlias == 'md') {
         this.viewCourses = split(this.courses,2);
      }
      if ( change.mqAlias == 'lg') {
         this.viewCourses = split(this.courses,3);
      }
    });


<div fxLayout style="margin-top: 40px" class="row">
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport [itemSize]="20" class="example-viewport">
      <div *cdkVirtualFor="let courses of viewCourses">
        <div fxFlex.gt-md="265px" fxFlex.lg="265px" *ngFor="let course of courses">
        <mat-card class="course-card" >
         ...content
        </mat-card>
        </div>
      </div>
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the solution to this. It seems weird when the card suddenly changed to another card before finished.

What I did:

CSS file:

1. make height of each item fit-content:

   .number {
   height: fit-content;
   }
2. make the container class:

   .container {
   min-height: 100vh;
   }
3. then in the template:

   The ID: {{ sundanese.number }}
  {{ sundanese.arab }}
  {{ sundanese.id }}

It worked for me. I hope it works for you too.

Comment: well, number 3 is not what I meant. The code formatter not working as properly here.